# Making more appealing the look of a bar plot with data of different magnitudes

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, bar-chart

I have this barplot generated by simply calling the `bar` method of matplotlib, my problem is that while most of the data are of the same order of magnitude, there are a few bars that are so long to squash the rest of the bars in a way you can't compare them. Here are the results:

[image]

I would like to plot the rest of the data, as if the higher bars were not there and for the higher bars just to reach the top of the plot and have their real value displayed on them.

Is it possible?

For completeness, here is how I generated the plot:

```
def plot_states_meanvar(l, ax):
    xs, means, var = zip(*l)
    xs = np.array(xs)
    for x in xs:
        ax.bar(x - 0.25/2, means[x], color = 'b', width = 0.25)
        ax.bar(x + 0.25/2, var[x], color = 'g', width = 0.25)
def plot_meanvar(meanvars, title=None):
    fig, axs = plt.subplots(ncols=3, nrows=2)
    for (modeldata, ax) in zip(meanvars, fig.axes):
        plot_states_meanvar(modeldata, ax)
    if title is not None:
        fig.suptitle(title)
    plt.tight_layout()
```

Comment: `ax.set_ylim()`? Or change to log scale?

Comment: How do I change to log scale?

Comment: https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_yscale.html

Comment: @GerardoZinno the `ylim` trick flips the ax because you set only the max, but `ylim` when it sees only one value in its arguments thinks it's the minimum. Try instead `plt.ylim((0, ymax))` (the argument is a 2-tuple) or `plt.ylim(top=ymax)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to change the y-axis to a log scale using [`Axes.set_yscale`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_yscale.html):

```
ax.set_yscale('log')
```